# Sending array of data to PHP at server from vb.Net

Tags: php, arrays, json, vb.net

I don't know if this is even possible, and I can't figure how to achieve this.

I have 50 (can be more) records in `MS Access` database that I wish to send to a a `php file` at my server for further processing.

What I have implemented so far is that I loop through the records and send them one by one. This kind of takes time cause of network issues, some records will be sent and others won't and each data sent will have to wait for report from server before the next one will be sent.

Is there a way I can send all records once, maybe in an array or something and be able to access it at the server side?

Below is my table schema.

```
--------------------------
|  id  |  phone  |  msg  |
--------------------------
|  1   | 09023023|  hi   |
|  2   | 09023024|  hey  |
|  3   | 09023025|  dear |  
--------------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use Json.. Convert the results into a Json object and pass it at a go

Comment: @TusharGupta thanks, was able to solve this using your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this. I don't know if it is the best way out there but it worked well.

On `@Tushar Gupta` suggestion, I created a `Json Array` using a third party `Json Library` found at http://www.newtonsoft.com/

I looped through the data in the database and concatenated them like so:

**CODE**

```
    Dim sms As New Sms 'note that this is a class
    Dim sms_obj As String = ""


    Try
        conn.Open()

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("id, phone, msg FROM sms;", conn)

        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader


        'collate sms
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While reader.Read()

            sms.id = reader("id").ToString()
            sms.member_phone = reader("phone").ToString()
            sms.member_message = reader("msg").ToString()


            If sms_obj = "" Then
                sms_obj = sms_obj + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sms, Formatting.Indented)
            Else
                sms_obj = sms_obj + "," + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sms, Formatting.Indented)
            End If

        End While

        sms_obj = "{ ""sms""" + ":" + "[" + sms_obj + "]}" ' this put the json string in an array

        'close the connection
        conn.Close()


        If sms.ToString <> "" Then
            HelperModule.SendSms(sms_obj)
        End If


        lblSmsState.Text = "sending sms done!"

    Catch ex As Exception
        msgbox(ex.toString())
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    { "sms":[
          {
            "id": "1",
            "member_phone": "09023023",
            "member_message": "hi"
          },{
            "id": "2",
            "member_phone": "09023024",
            "member_message": "hey"
          },{
            "id": "3",
            "member-phone": "09023025",
            "member_message": "dear"
          }

        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are exactly trying to achieve but you could use MYSQL or phpmyAdmin

you could also in the excel file add `$id = (` at the top of the column and then use commas to separate the records (<kbd>CTRL + F</kbd> replace may be useful) and end the column with `);`. You may want to follow the same procedure with phone and msg too, then save the file as a CSV or make it into single line or perhaps copy the data in your text editor and that should save it as an array.

php also makes use of multi dimensional array, which you can read up and can store everything in one array (not recommended as not efficient).